# How to convert calendar identifier into string in swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have used this statement in Swift 2.3 but got error on Swift 3

```
let initCalendarType:String = userCalendar.identifier as String
```

The error is *"Cannot convert value of type 'Calendar.Identifier' to type 'String' in coercion"*

Can anyone please help convert it to Swift 3?

Thanks
Toy9b

Comment: Can you please add what error you are getting.

Comment: The error is "Cannot convert value of type 'Calendar.Identifier' to type 'String' in coercion"

Answer (score 0):

The property `identifier` in the class `Calendar` in Swift 3 is now an enumeration.

```
let initCalendarType = userCalendar.identifier
if initCalendarType == .gregorian {
    print("initCalendarType is", initCalendarType)
}
```

The type `Calendar.Identifier` seems to conform to `CustomStringConvertible`,
if you really need a string use String Interpolation

```
let initCalendarType = "\(userCalendar.identifier)"
```

Comment: Thanks Vadian but how to assign it as String from Calendar.Identifier?

Comment: Thanks Vadian.

I totally forgot this way you had answered me. :)